# How to write output of a shell command to a socket in c?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I'm trying to implement a basic ftp client-server program. The client should be able to connect to the server and navigate it through commands like cd and ls. I was wondering how could I write the output of the exec command to the client shell window. I thought about copying the output to a file and then sending it to the client but I am looking for something more elegant. This is the code I've written which outputs the command on the server shell.

server.cpp

```
  if(strcmp(command[0],"cd")==0)
    chdir(command[1]);

  pid=fork();

  if(pid==0){

    if(strcmp(command[0],"cd")==0){
      cout<<"Changed working directory to: ";
      printf("%s\n",command[1]);
      cout<<"Contents of working directory:\n";
      execl("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
    }
    if(strcmp(command[0],"ls")==0){
      cout<<"Contents of working directory:\n";
      execl("/bin/ls","ls",command[1],NULL);
    }
    else if(strcmp(command[0],"chmod")==0){
      cout<<"Changed permissions of ";
      printf("%s",command[2]);
      cout<<" to ";
      printf("%s\n",command[1]);
      execl("/bin/chmod","chmod",command[1],command[2],NULL);
    }
    exit(0);
  }
  if(pid > 0)
    wait(NULL);
```

How can I get it in the client shell? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not C .

Comment: Instead of spawning child processes to do those things, you'd be better off just implementing them yourself in the same process.  For example, instead of spawning off a "chmod" subclass, call the chmod() system function (as described in "man 2 chmod").  Instead of spawning off an "ls" child process, call opendir()/readdir()/closedir() to generate the text yourself.  Instead of spawning off a "cd" subprocess, call chdir().  Etc.

Comment: That's a good suggestion but would it work with flags like "ls - a" or  "ls - l"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this time, your server has established a socket connection to the client.

After the `fork()`, but before the `exec()`, `dup()` the socket to file descriptor 1, standard output, before `exec()`ing the external command. Since its standard output will be connected to the socket, the client will get the output.

You should also `close()` all other socket file descriptors, before the `exec()`, so that the child process doesn't inherit them. This won't do any real harm in the case of `ls`, but is the expected practice.

Comment: Doesn't this enforce a process per connection design? isn't that sub-optimal?

Comment: I'm not complaining, I'm aware that they started it ;-)

Comment: You are starting a new process for the `ls` command. Whether your main server process starts its own subprocess for each connection, or whether the main server process handles all simultaneous connections, is not a factor (except for the detail of closing all client connection sockets before the child process `exec`s `ls`).

Comment: I do realize that this is sub-optimal but i need to use exec() for commands like "ls -l"  and I couldn't find an alternative to fork() to achieve this.